# How to retrieve items inside of the array instead of the array itself in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, javascript-objects

My data comes from the user and gets stored as an object, that object needs to go into Mongo after some massaging on the server side. I am using Mongoose and using the `$push {item}` syntax to insert an item into my DB.

My Mongoose Model has `photos: []` as the syntax, just a simple array. Inside of that array I need the photos uploaded. But if the users uploads at different times my array could end up with an array of arrays, and I just need one simple array with multiple objects.

Here is my route:

```
const testMedia = async (req, res) => {
  //loop through the res.locals.ids and save each as their own photo in the event
  let events = [];
  let photosArray =
  let owner = {id: req.user._id};
  const promises =  await res.locals.ids.map((photoLink) => {
     events.push({link: photoLink.link,
     dateUploaded: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
     eventID: req.body.eventId,
     owner: owner
     })
  });
  await Event.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.body.eventId,
      { $push: {
        photos: events
      }},
      { save: true, upsert: true, new: true },
      (err) => {
        if (err){
          console.log("Error in testMedia  ||  " + err);
          res.sendStatus(300);
        }
      }
    );

  await Promise.all(promises);
  res.render("eventDisplay", { events: event });
  res.end();
};
```

The problem that I am running into is that if I push the items into `events` I will be pushing an array of objects when I need just the objects themselves, so either I have to make one database call per object to insert, which seems like a waste of resources, or I need to find a way to insert all of the objects without wrapping them in an array.

For some reason I can't figure this out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Mongo docs, you can use `$each`

```
.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.eventId, {
  $push: {
    photos: { $each: events }
  }
})
```

This will push multiple items into your array.

Comment: Thank you very much! Wow so simple. I'll go through the docs and see how I missed it.